# Where from can we configure code formatter in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio, settings, visual-studio-code, code-formatting

The code formatting is available in VS Code through the following shortcuts:

```
On Windows Shift + Alt + F
On Mac Shift + Option + F
On Ubuntu Ctrl + Shift + I
```

But I want to configure how to format, where do I find those settings?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the language that you use.

VS Code is bundled with **HTML**, **JSON**, **JavaScript**, **TypeScript** formatters, each one with its own customizations. You can see the available configurations in `Preferences: Open User Settings`

But, if you use another language, like **C#**, **Java**, **Delphi**, etc, will need to see if that extension also comes with a formatter (search for `Formatter` tag in the [extension`s category](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?target=VSCode&category=Formatters&sortBy=Downloads)). Otherwise, you should look for standalone formatter extensions available.